# Why set explicitly enum's value when can leave the compiler set?

Tags: c, enums

generally I see `enum { A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, ... }` is there some special reason to just set `A` value and leave the compiler set next value to previous member value + 1 or is this programmer's trying do code more readable or something like this?

Comment: Readability. For the compiler, `enum { A = 1, B, C, ... }` is equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a stylistic issue. Specifying the values indicates that your application cares about the specific values that each enum takes on, perhaps because it's used to implement a published standard, or for interoperability with some other application whose interface specifies particular integers.

Even if the values in the specification happen to be sequential, it's good idea to enter them explicitly. Leaving them out makes errors more likely, if you enter the members in the wrong order, or someone later inserts a member in the middle of the list.

On the other hand, if you don't care what the specific values are, and just need the compiler to assign arbitrary unique values to each enum member, you leave the values out and let the compiler do it automatically. This is appropriate for enums that are just used internally within your application.